# How to change position of a point/vertex in GWT maps polyline?

Tags: google-maps, gwt, polyline

I am using GWT google-maps.
I know how to draw a polyline and then edit it by calling setEditingEndabled(true).
I can change a single point by using mouse, manually.
However, if I want to change a point/vertex programmatically, What should I do?
polyline.insertVertex() will introduce new vertex. What I need is moving the current vertex around.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
polyline.deleteVertex(index);
polyline.insertVertex(index, newVertex);
```